# how to remove quotes only from start and end in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string

`'{"userId":"NiouCzjBYnax3UST5tDc2","file_Name":["abc.PNG","cdf.PNG","cbc.PNG","shs.PNG"],"url":["images/NiouCx3UST5tDc2/2020-01-23/sas.PNG","images/Niox3UST5tDc2/2020-01-23/R-CC.PNG","images/NiouCzjBYna8WST5tDc2/2020-01-23/sas.PNG","images/NiouCzj3UST5tDc2/2020-01-23/jka.PNG"]}'`

Comment: you want to remove qoutes or you want to load this as json?

Comment: Converting a JSON string to a `dict` literal involves more than just removing the outer quotes.

Comment: if you really just want to remove the first and last character you can use slicing a = string[1:-1], but I guess the other answers are more helpful

Answer (score 2):

The outer quotes make that a string. Removing characters from a string still returns a string...

If I understand correctly, you should parse the string

```
import json
data = json.loads(string)
```

Comment: thanks.. i tried this json.loads() but even after that i am getting this ERROR  > Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)  i want to fetch the information from my json .

Comment: That would mean the string you're loading is empty